# Setting up Shopify recurring billing API with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, shopify-app

I've been trying to set up recurring billing for a shopify app built with [Shopify's Rails App Gem](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app).  The gem itself is great, but there is nothing there to deal with billing.

There is a an [outdated billing project](https://github.com/Shopify/billing-demo-app/blob/master/config/routes.rb) that I hasn't been super helpful.  I was hoping that any of you might have had to deal with this lately and could point me to a good repo, or stub out highlevel instructions on how to start using the billing api.

Answer (score 1):

In your embedded App controller, use a before filter.

```
before_action :require_subscription
```

In your private method, require_subscription you are free to setup a session and check if the shop has a charge that makes you happy. If not, make one. If they do, carry on. If they have a pending one, activate it. Etc.

You do not need an engine, nor a complex repo to accomplish using the billing API. A simple filter response has done quite well for me anyway.

Comment: Thanks a million David, this did it for me. I was way overcomplicating things for myself.

Comment: Right on! I am all for simple.